# How do I set up a .emacs initialization file?

Tags: emacs

I am using Linux Fedora 13 (Constantine) and emacs 23.1.1. I am trying to set up a .emacs file for initialization, by using emacs itself to edit and save a file .emacs in my home directory. However, although the file is there, emacs does not seem to recognize it. What might I be doing wrong, and is there a simple text for .emacs that will show me if it is being used, one that will display a message on emacs start up?

Answer (score 3):

The [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) is traditionally `~/.emacs`, but modern versions also look at [other names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init). There may be confusion about what your home directory is (there shouldn't be on unix platforms, though; this is mostly a problem under Windows); opening `~/.emacs` inside Emacs is always right. After Emacs has started, check for messages in the `*Messages*` buffer. Make sure you're not running Emacs with options like `-q` that would tell it to bypass your init file.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an error in your .emacs file in your home directory. Try opening your .emacs file and then M-x eval-buffer RET to check if you see if you get any errors you might have missed. Emacs will run the .emacs file in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If you put something illegal at the start of the .emacs file and emacs really is reading it, I would expect it to fail on startup.  For example if I put a line containing

```
Hello William
```

at the first line of my .emacs the program gives me the warning

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: Hello
```

and fails to load the remainder of the file.

You could use `strace` (or the Fedora equivalent, perhaps truss, dtruss etc) to trace the system calls and look for where emacs tries to open .emacs in the output.  For example under the bash shell:

```
strace emacs 2> strace-ouput.txt
```